# Syntax highlighting for Jade in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, pug, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I just started using Sublime Text 2 on Mac. I also just started using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) for my views in Node.js, and am wondering if there is a way to add syntax highlighting for Jade into Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 supports Textmate syntax definition files. There is a Jade Textmate bundle at https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle.

Install by creating a new folder in your Sublime Text "Packages" folder, call the new folder `Jade`, then `curl -O https://raw.github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle/master/Syntaxes/Jade.tmLanguage` or otherwise download that file into the new folder. The editor will load the syntax immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Just for those who did not know it (me, for example), the packages folder on Linux is ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages

Comment: Worked like a charm! On OS X Lion it's ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/

Comment: Windows: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages. Or on any platform just go to Preferences > Browse Packages in the editor to find the directory.

Comment: +1 Worked great in Mountain Lion.  Didn't even have to reload or restart Sublime.  Might this replace Textmate for me?  lol

Comment: This worked for me too! But I had to restart Sublime.

Answer (score 179):

If you have git installed, this worked perfectly for me:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages
git clone https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle Jade
```

**Bonus** to get stylus syntax highlighting working run:

```
git clone https://github.com/stylus/stylus.git Stylus
```

Comment: just the 'follow these steps' response i was looking for.

Comment: @jurka For Ubuntu: ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages

Comment: This worked for me on Mountain Lion. Make sure you reboot Sublime after installing this to see the syntax highlighting.

Comment: For Windows (7 at least) use: /c/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages

Comment: **+1** *(Just to clarify)* Works on **Linux Mint Maya MATE AMD64**

Comment: THE AUTHOR HAS NOT MAINTAINED THIS REPO!  A more recent repo is at https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle

Comment: I initially thought that this did not work, but then discovered that Sublime had not automatically set the correct syntax for Jade files that were already open before I restarted Sublime. Simple matter to set the syntax or even just reopen the Jade file once I realized this.

Answer (score 74):

Why yes, there is! And it uses a nice packaging system too:

1. If you need to, install Package Control from [here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)
2. Open the command palette (command + shift + P) and go to Package Control (just type "install"). You may need to wait for the repository to be updated.
3. When in package control type "jade" to find the Jade Syntax Highlighting package. Hit enter to install it.

You now have syntax highlighting for Jade and a nifty package controller for other Sublime goodies. [This search](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/jade) shows a lot of available tools for working with Jade, Jade+Bootstrap, pyjade, etc

**Edit** - Sublime doesn't need to be restarted after installing this package so this step was removed.

Comment: Best answer! :) I didn't even restart as it was immediately available. I just picked the syntax from the list for already opened files. The new highlighter was already associated with .jade files.

Comment: Yeah, Package Control is amazing. It's only (very minor) flaw is that you can't use it for /everything/, as sometimes (rarely) language packs etc. don't get included in its list.

Comment: I do not see the Jade syntax highlighting package in the list - maybe it is no longer available?  There is a Textmate/Sublime bundle from davidrios.

Comment: @SnapShot The bundle from davidrios will give you syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 10):

@jurka -

- OS X:
  `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/`
- Linux:
  `~/.Sublime Text 2/Packages/`
- Windows:
  `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 2/Packages/`

Clone into the path shown above for linux.

Comment: On Mac: Open Sublime; CMD+Shift+P; Install Package; Jade

Answer (score 5):

Jade is also available via the [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu 11.10 correct path to packages for me is ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages
You can easily find your packages location using Menu: "Preferences" -> "Browse Packages..."

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer refers to a plugin that is deprecated and no longer active.
For those who are still looking for a supported Jade plugin for Sublime Text, you should use this repo:

https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle

This is also on Package Control:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jade

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac:

Go to Library/Applciation Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ then,

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle/master/Syntaxes/Jade.tmLanguage
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made the following on linux `ST2 build 2221`:

```
git clone https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle.git Jade.tmbundle
```

Then

```
zip -r Jade.zip Jade.tmbundle/
mv Jade.zip Jade.sublime-package
mv Jade.sublime-package /sublime_folder_location/Pristine Packages/
```