# How to save as jade file?

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to use jade, i am currently using sublime text 2, when i go to save my file there is no option to save as a jade file, Do i have to use something that can save as a jade file or can i use sublime and just save the file as file.jade. I seen this answer [Syntax highlighting for Jade in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666977/syntax-highlighting-for-jade-in-sublime-text-2) but, i am not understand what to do im on windows 8, i have never used github before and i see like 10 things i can click on when i click this link, https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle i think i may rather use something from google chrome, i know they have a editor that supports jade. Anyone know of a good free editor or just something i can use to just save jade files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to activate "file extensions" to do so, in older windows versions it was disabled on default. 
To activate just open your explorer, hit view then, under options, click on folder options or something like that. There you find "Hide file extensions", deactivate this checkbox. 
After that you can save files in Sublime in every format you want to, like *@henguin1001* mentioned before.

Comment: i did what you said i can save as a ton of different ext now but jade is still not one of the options.

Comment: Hit 'Save as' then at the point where to find your preferred extension , hit to something called "All ...", then name your file yourFilename.jade and save it.

Comment: i am trying this and when i go to localhost it's asking me how i want to open the file, where as if i had just a html file in this instead of  jade it would just work. i save the file as all like you said and added the jade ext

Comment: Oh i got it. You have to start your app with: node yourApp.js then open localhost:YourPort.

Comment: var express = require('express');

var app = express();
 
app.set('view engine','jade')

app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/empty.jade');
});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: this is my jade file     !!! 5
html
  head
    link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/site.css')
    title Hello
  body
    h1 Hello world!

Comment: yes right question, im trying to use the jade file with express and node.js

Comment: Yes, this looks fine. But as I sad before you have to start your app. Maybe you want to take a look here in this tutorial:
[Node.js & Express Basic Tutorial](http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/)

Comment: i am starting my app,if i use a html file it works fine, but if i use the jade file, it says how do i want to open the file.

Comment: Don't browse for localhost:youPort/yourFile.jade, instead open localhost:yourPort/yourFile and add a route to your app for yourFile. As I sad, this tutorial from above will show you all steps.

Comment: @ morenulls ok i see, I will do it as you said and try it out. I didn't think i would matter, ty i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Save As -> then add the extension .jade, or rename your txt file with that extension and there is even a sublime text plugin for jade https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jade