# How do I make jade syntax color highlight in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am working with a Jade file and found that on Mac it's highlighted but on Windows it's not.

I hope to highlight HTML tag keywords like `div` or `script` and all inline JavaScript code.

Thanks,

Comment: In ST 2 there is no build-in support for Jade. You must have a highlight plugin for Jade on your Mac but not on your Windows machine.

Comment: @user555 Do you where I can get one? I don't remember I've installed any plugins for this particularly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666977/syntax-highlighting-for-jade-in-sublime-text-2